# Bash reload to find an executable after installing from a script

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, nvm

I'm trying to write a little shell script to install `nvm` and then to install a node version specified in the `.nvmrc` file. The installation of `nvm` seems to be succesful, but I can not call `nvm install`, because `$(command -v nvm)` has no output. Also in the terminal, I get the message from the `nvm` `install.sh` script:

> => Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! [ -x "$(command -v nvm)" ]; then
  echo 'Installing Node version manager (http://nvm.sh).' >&2
  curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
fi

source ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bashrc

if [ -x "$(command -v nvm)" ]; then
  nvm install
  exit
fi
exit 1
```

How to use the command `nvm` in the bash script?

Comment: Did you try `hash -r nvm`? Though probably you also need to reload your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` if it made edits to that. ("Do the following" probably explains in more detail what exactly you need, but you don't reveal where this quote is from so I can't check.)

Comment: @tripleee I've added `source ~/.bash_profile` and `source ~/.bashrc` to the script file. Could you clarify what `hash -r nvm` does? I get no output for `hash -r nvm` in a bash, where I can call `nvm` successfully.

Comment: @tripleee thx now I know what `hash -r nvm` does. It solved my problem. :)

Comment: But now I see, that `if ! [ -x "$(command -v nvm)" ];` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply modify the environment with the command given by the script without reloading the whole profile use :

```
eval "$(curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash | grep -E -v "^.?=>")"
```

`grep` will remove the comments starting with `=>` and potentially a leading hidden character.
`eval` will execute the commands in the current shell.

then do not use `-x` since `command -v nvm` returns nvm and not the full path.

```
if [ -n "$(command -v nvm)" ]; then
  nvm install
  exit $?
fi
```

And following triplee advice use a bare `exit` to keep the return code.

Script becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! [ -n "$(command -v nvm)" ]; then
  echo 'Installing Node version manager (http://nvm.sh).' >&2
  eval "$(curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash | grep -E -v "^.?=>")"
fi

if [ -n "$(command -v nvm)" ]; then
  nvm install
  exit
fi
exit 1
```

Comment: Thx for your annswer. `if ! [ -x "$(command -v nvm)" ];` does not work. Even if `nvm` is already installed, the if block is executed.

Comment: That is what I said, -x check the path when command -v nvm returns nvm. So I changed the test to -n that checks if the string is not empty and then it works well.

Comment: Sorry I mean, `if ! [ -n "$(command -v nvm)" ];` does not work. Even if `nvm` is already installed, the if block is executed.